# Visual Studio - Output number on lines that contain at least one Chinese symbol

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to go through our project and find out exactly how many lines contain Chinese symbols?

This also needs to exclude any lines starting with `/*` or `//`

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That question was in regards to searching through text. I want the output of how many lines contain Chinese symbols

Comment: The regular expression can be reused ... if you can search then you can count the matches.

Comment: In Visual Studio, the Find Results window gives you a count.